# Visual Studio Queries open in Browser instead of inside Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2017, workitem

In Visual Studio 2017 When I am clicking on a Query it opens in a browser instead of opening (like it used to) inside visual studio

How can I change this to be opened in visual studio?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2017 (aka VS version 15) the default behaviour for opening work items has been changed to browser. You can switch back to the old behaviour: Open Tools > Options > Work Items and change "Open work items in" to "Visual Studio".

More details here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/08/22/work-items-now-open-in-the-web-from-visual-studio-15/

Comment: FWIW: In VS2019, under Work Items -> General.   It is now called "Landing Page: Legacy Experience".

Comment: In VS 2022 it's _Landing Page: Legacy Experience (compatibility mode)_ and it "will be deprecated in the next major version of Visual Studio."